# Fetching data from URL returning nothing

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to fetch data from this URL "http://website.com/Categories.js"

and using react native fetch API inside componentDidMount and when i printed it nothing is returned and here is the full example on Snack :
[Snack.expo](https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/fetch)
also here is the docs i am following:
[React native networking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network)

and here is my code:

```
componentWillMount=async()=>{
   const res = await fetch('http://website.com/Categories.js');
   const data = await res.json();
   console.log(data);
}
```

how can i fetch this exported data properly ?

Comment: You also should be getting a `FetchError: invalid json response body at... etc.` if you look in the console.

Comment: You have to store the raw JSON object you wish to GET at that url, not a file that is exporting it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should not ansychronize `componentWillMount` and/or `componentDidMount`: those funcitons are provided by React and should be used as is.

This could be the cause of your problem.

So I would suggest to modify your code in this way:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
   (async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://website.com/Categories.js');
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
    })()
}
```

Comment: i agree , also i tried to fetch javascript file instead of JSON.